# JSX in React component shows cyrillic text as habra-codabra

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

I create a standard ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Application with a React Redux template.

In the Home component I want to change english language to cyrillic text like so:

[image]

When I ran it locally this code renders as the following:

[image]

Looks like JSX doesn't compile the files into UTF8 encoding. But I don't know how to check what encoding the files compiled to and how to change this behaviour.

Can you please advise me on that?

**UPDATE:**

In the head tag of index.html the charset is set to utf-8:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the encoding of the Home.js  then.

Comment: Most of the editors have an option to save with a specified encoding or reopen with encoding. I suspect that Home.js is not encoded as UTF-8, maybe try checking encoding in the editor? JSX trasformers such as Babel and tsc don't affect the encoding.

Comment: Thanks, js file had Windows-1251 encoding. Спасибо, js file был в Windows-1251 кодировке

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Alexey Lebedev told the Home.js file had Windows-1251 encoding. After I changed the encoding manually in text editor to UTF-8, Cyrillic began to be displayed correctly.

Comment: Try Visual Studio Code. It helped me.